# How can I update react app that gets it's data from the node mongo backend using redux

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux

your help will be highly appreciated. I have been working on a react crud application with Redux. I am able to delete, add and even get an information from the node express backend but I am unable to update the app.
I want to be able to click on the edit button and get target information on the edit page like the id, description and other things.
This is the edit component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { updateIssue, fetchIssue } from '../actions/IssueAction';

class EditIssue extends Component {
  state = {
    description: '',
    severity: '',
    assignedTo: '',
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { description, severity, assignedTo } = this.props.Issues;
    this.setState({
      description: description,
      severity: severity,
      assignedTo: assignedTo,
    });
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };
  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const post_Issue = {
      description: this.state.description,
      severity: this.state.severity,
      assignedTo: this.state.assignedTo,
    };

    this.props.updateIssue(post_Issue);

    window.location = '/';
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Add New Issue</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Description: </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="description"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Describe the issue..."
              value={this.state.description}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Severity</label>
            <select
              name="severity"
              className="form-control"
              value={this.state.severity}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            >
              <option value="Low">Low</option>
              <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
              <option value="High">High</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Assigned To: </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="assignedTo"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Enter Responsible..."
              value={this.state.assignedTo}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              type="submit"
              value="Update the issue"
              className="btn btn-primary"
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  Issues: state.Issues,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { updateIssue, fetchIssue })(EditIssue);
```

this is the action file for update

```
export const updateIssue = (post_Issue) => (dispatch) => {
  console.log('Edit clicked');
  axios
    .post(`http://localhost:5000/issues/update/${post_Issue._id}`, post_Issue)
    .then((res) =>
      dispatch({
        type: EDIT_ISSUE,
        payload: res.data,
      })
    );
};
```

and this is the reducer

```
import {
    FETCH_ISSUE,
    POST_ISSUE,
    DELETE_ISSUE,
    EDIT_ISSUE,
    ITEMS_LOADING
} from '../actions/type';

const initialState = {
    Issues: [],
    loading: false
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_ISSUE:
            return {
                ...state,
                Issues: action.payload,
                    loading: false
            };
        case POST_ISSUE:
            return {
                ...state,
                Issues: [action.payload, ...state.Issues]
            };
        case DELETE_ISSUE:
            return {
                ...state,
                Issues: state.Issues.filter(Issue => Issue._id !== action.payload)
            };
        case EDIT_ISSUE:
            return {
                ...state,
                Issues: [action.payload, ...state.Issues]
            };
        case ITEMS_LOADING:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in your reducers and action.

```
//this will add new element instead updating selected existing one.
    case EDIT_ISSUE:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    Issues: [action.payload, ...state.Issues]
                };
```

Update action and reducer as per below.

```
export const updateIssue = (post_Issue) => (dispatch, getState) => { //add getState

  const issues = getState().Issues; // get all issues

  axios
    .post(`http://localhost:5000/issues/update/${post_Issue._id}`, post_Issue)
    .then((res) => {
      //update selected issue after api success 
      for (let index = 0; index < issues.length; index++) {
        if (issue._id === post_Issue._id) {
          let selectedIssue = issues[index];
          selectedIssue = { ...selectedIssue, ...post_Issue };
          issues[index] = selectedIssue;
        }
      }
      //dispatch updated issues lists
      dispatch({
        type: EDIT_ISSUE,
        payload: issues,
      })
    }
    );
};
```

**Reducer**

```
case EDIT_ISSUE:
return {
  ...state,
  Issues: state.Issues // re-asssign issues
};
```

Comment: Hello! I have made the changes above but still confused of where the issue._id in the axios post within the if statement comes from. It shows an error, that it can't be found

Answer (score 0):

this can be done quite simply.

Just call reducer action in componentDidMount with that data id ( fetching with id is for get right data byId in db ) and get updated prop in componentDidUpdate after node js has responded like below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { updateIssue, fetchIssue } from '../actions/IssueAction';

class EditIssue extends Component {
  state = {
    description: '',
    severity: '',
    assignedTo: '',
  };

  componentDidMount() {
// you need to figure out a way to have id here ... as a props or state 
const { id, fetchIssue } = this.props;
 fetchIssue(id)


  }

componentDidUpdate() {
if(this.props.Issues.length ){ 
const { description, severity, assignedTo } = this.props.Issues;
    this.setState({
      description: description,
      severity: severity,
      assignedTo: assignedTo,
    });

}

}

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };
  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const post_Issue = {
      description: this.state.description,
      severity: this.state.severity,
      assignedTo: this.state.assignedTo,
    };

    this.props.updateIssue(post_Issue);

    window.location = '/';
  };

  render() {
if(!this.props.Issue) return <div> return something else since this is before node js respond </div>;
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Add New Issue</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        // your form fields...
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  Issues: state.Issues,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { updateIssue, fetchIssue })(EditIssue);
```

don't forget to render some other jsx elements before node js responds like my example above.

I hope it helpful !!

Comment: Hello! I have made the above changes but gets an error coming from the fetchIssue(id). I don't even understand where it comes from. fetchIssue is the action for getting issues from the database.

Comment: You need to have id in componentDidMount, I edited my answer to clarify what I mean

Comment: Ok! made that change. Now shouldn't it be this.props.fetchIssue(id) instead of fetchIssue(id)

Comment: all the changes applied. Now I think the problem might be from the action

Comment: This is how the reducer looks `case EDIT_ISSUE:
return {
  ...state,
  Issues: state.Issues 
};`

Comment: There is no error but the inform from the specific data doesn't get into the form, so that's why an error might be in the action

Comment: can you check if the response successfully returns after axios request ?